# Program for drawing patent illustrations

Tags: software-recommendation, free

Is there a free cad or similar program that would be good for making drawings that will be submitted as part of a patent application?

Comment: Good start for hunting could be [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/autocad/?license=free). Unfortunately, I don't have any real world experience on those, but at least it's a start :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use Google SketchUp perhaps?

Comment: SketchUp is a very capable CAD option. And Free (tho the paid version is well worth it if you end up using it a lot).